# Issue trying to run chrome in a bash script on mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm attempting to get the version of chrome through a bash script on mac. I can run the following command fine directly from the terminal:

```
macbook-pro:jenkins_server$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
Google Chrome 87.0.4280.67
```

But when I try to put something like this in side of a bash script:

```
EXEC="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
"$EXEC" --version
```

I get the following result:

```
macbook-pro:jenkins_server$ ./test_script.sh 
./test_script.sh: line 2: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

Here you escaped spaces (`\` ) to tell the shell that this string is whole, not program and its arguments.

Alternative is to use quotes, i.e. `foo "a b"` is effectively the same as `foo a\ b`. When we are using quotes, we don't escape spaces, so it should be:

```
EXEC="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

Answer (score 0):

You double-quoted. `"foo bar"` is already equivalent to `foo\ bar` (really, `\f\o\o\ \b\a\r`, but except for the space, none of the characters has a special meaning that needed to be escaped, so e.g. `\f` evaluates to `f`).

`"foo\ bar"`, then, is equivalent to `foo\\\ bar`; the quoted backslash is *literal*, rather than quoting the following space.